# In Meshlab - when finding surface area of a trimmed model - Am I getting just the outer surface of the model or the inner as well?

Tags: meshlab

I have made 3D models of small coral skeletons (size of toy army men) that are placed on a hard surface and then scanned. This leaves a hole in the bottom of the model - which I close. I want to find the surface area of just the coral part - but not the very bottom surface.

My current workflow is to open my .obj in Meshlab, scale my model, then clean-up the model and remove things I don't want, then close the hole on the bottom, then go to Filters>Quality Measure and Computation>Compute Geometric Measures to compute the surface area of the total model including the bottom.

I then remove/delete all of the coral and just leave the bottom surface (which has a top now)  and run Filters>Quality Measure and Computation>Compute Geometric Measures again to get just the surface area of the bottom (?) - my Question is: since the model now has two surfaces - Is Meshlab giving me just the bottom surface area or including the newly fashioned top surface as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you say the surface has a top. They should be triangles that are rendered by two sides, but it is a single surface. So the response is that meshlab is giving just the area of the bottom surface.

Despite that, I will propose you one alternative method which seems easier.

Just after closing the hole on the bottom (with the `Close Holes` filter) you should see that the new triangles are selected. Invoke the filter `Compute Area/Perimeter of selection` (located in `Filters`->`Quality measure and Computations`) and you will see the area of the selection, which is your desired value.

[image]

Comment: Yes - you are right. I was proposing to delete the top portion of the model, leaving just the bottom part. Not a good way to do it. Your way is way more efficient. I also found some info for copying the selection to a different layer and then running compute geometric measures which gives the same answer, but is more steps. Thank you for your comments